# Interpretation of Pooled OLS model with log transformed independent variable

Tags: regression, interpretation

I have run two pooled OLS regression models on the same data set, one where the independent variable of interest is left in its original form and on where it has been log transformed. Lagged hateful replies is a measure of exposure to hate speech online, while the dependent variable, posts containing hate speech, is a measure of the adoption of hateful speech.

I wanted to check that the following interpretation is correct: in both instances the coefficient on exposure to hate speech is positive and statistically significant. That is to say, that an increase in exposure to an additional post containing hate speech is associated with an additional 0.38 hateful posts for each forum member. The interpretation of log transformed independent variables is as follows; dividing the coefficient by 100 gives us the change in the dependent variable due to a one percent increase in the independent variable. Thus, a one percent increase in exposure is associated with an increase in hateful posts of 0.12.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your interpretations are correct but it would be helpful if you clarified which version (1,2, or 3) is being used in discussing them.

Comment: Thanks Mike and apologies, yes, I should have been clearer that I was talking about model 1 in this example. In addition to this, if we consider the logged independent variable example (Table 2, model 1) would it be the case that doubling ones exposure to hateful comments is associated with an increase in the adoption of hate speech by: 12.167 * ln(1.100) =  3.66

Comment: First of all, why be so diffident about model-based claims? Your calcs are straight-forward, textbook examples. Next, model 1 has a single parameter and the lowest r-square. Why use it *at all* for prediction?

Comment: I'm not used to working log transformed independent variables, so I just wanted to make sure that the interpretations I was making were correct. I only used that example in the question because it was the simplest model therefore the least to interpret.